# Causing a buffer overflow in C to force a true condition

Tags: c, input, buffer-overflow

I'm trying to solve this challenge where the goal is to get the program to display "YOU WIN!"  To do this I must find the right values ​​of the variables to make both the `if` condition and `assert` evaluate to true.

Originally I thought this would be relatively simple.  However, it seems that to make a buffer overflow is an art that requires advanced programming skills (big-endian and little-endian concepts too), but I do not have much experience in C programming.

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.

```
#include<assert.h>
int
main(int argc, char*argv[]){
    int size = 0;
    int buf[1024];
    read(0,&size,sizeof(size));
    assert (size <= 1024);
    read(0,buf,size*sizeof(int));
    if (size > 0 && size < 100 && buf[999] == 'B')
        printf("YOU WIN!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I can't really understand what you're asking. Can you clarify?

Comment: @phonon the question is: which input data should be supplied in order to produce the output "YOU WIN!"

Answer (score 4):

Fun problem.

You have to know something about the machine you're running on, so I made the
following assumptions:

1. 32-bit machine, big endian.
2. Compiler does "classical" stack layout, which would put `size` adjacent to the end of `buf`.
3. Data is aligned to 4 bytes or less so there is no padding between the end of `buf` and `size`.

The classic compiler on this machine allocates your variables on the call stack in the order they appear in the code, so `size` gets pushed first, and then `buf`.  Your stack will look like this:

```
                   buf                byte
   top of stack   offset             offset
   +-----------+    0 * sizeof(int) =    0  
   | buf[   0] |   
   +-----------+    1 * sizeof(int) =    4
   |           |   
   ...
   |           |
   +-----------+ 1023 * sizeof(int) = 4092
   | buf[1023] |
   +-----------+ 1024 * sizeof(int) = 4096
   |   size    |
   +-----------+ 1025 * sizeof(int) = 4100
  bottom of stack
```

Writing to `buf[1024]` would overwrite `size`.  If we were writing raw bytes,
then byte 4096, 4097, 4098, and 4099 would correspond to the bytes in `size`.

We know we want size to be negative to pass the `assert`, and we want `size * sizeof(int)`
to evaluate to 4100.  Because if we read 4100 bytes, the last 4 bytes will overwrite `size`.

```
size * 4 = 4100.  Solving for size:
size = 1025 (or 0x401)
```

Now we just make it negative by setting the most significant bit.

```
0x80000401
```

So setting size to this value will pass `assert (size <= 1024)`.  Because anything
with the most significant bit set is negative, and all negative numbers are less than 1024.

When we get to the buffer read, it will get evaluated like so:

```
read(0, buf, 0x80000401 * sizeof(int));
read(0, buf, 0x80000401 * 4);
read(0, buf, 0x00001004) == read(0, buf, 4100)
```

Yes, that's right, we just told it to read 4100 bytes because of 32-bit modulo arithmetic.  Or if it helps, you can think of multiplying by 4 as shifting left by 2, so shifting our magic value left by 2 gets rid of the most-significant bit.

To print "YOU WIN!", you'd write a stream of bytes, where buf[999] is byte 3996
and bytes 4096, 4097, 4098, and 4099 are the bytes of `size`.  On this hypothetical
big-endian machine, we'd set those bytes to 0, 0, 0, and 1-99, respectively.

Comment: `0x80000401` does not get you `-0x401`!  (That would be sign-magnitude, however two's complement is surely what OP's machine is using)

Comment: @Matt:  The intent wasn't to get `-0x401`, but rather to get a number, any number, that was negative when evaluated in a signed context in the assert while also becoming 4100 when multiplied by 4 in the size_t argument to `read`.  I thought it made more sense to set the sign bit instead of figuring out via modulo arithmetic that the number 2,147,484,673 worked.